# transform.Translate only for 10 units?

Tags: c#, unity

How can I `transform.Translate (Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 2);` a GameObject for 10 units? I mean only make it go up 10 units (10 y units).

Answer (score 1):

```
you can move a object 10 units up using
transform.Translate(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);
```

many ways to implement but I wrote this out to get you started

```
float yPos;
float yEnd;
void Start () {
    yPos = this.transform.position.y;
    yEnd = yPos + 10;     
}
void Update () {
    if(yPos < yEnd)
    {
        yPos = this.transform.position.y;
        transform.Translate(0.0f, 10.0f * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable as your target destination before you start moving, then use [Vector3.MoveTowards](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) to gradually move towards your destination.

You'll also want to specify a movement speed.

```
Vector3 targetPosition = transform.position + new Vector3(0, 10, 0);
float movementSpeed = 1f;

void Move () {
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```